# WP7 ListBox Scrolling Not Working

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I have the following XAML markup in a WP7 UserControl.  My problem is that when my ListBox has more items than will fit on a page it will not scroll properly.  I can scroll the list by panning upwards with my finger but as soon as I remove my finger it jumps back to the top of the list (if the list is very long then the scrolling will not even work to this limited extent).

I have tried numerous different layouts with no success e.g. Wrapping ListBox in ScrollViewer, utilising StackPanel instead of Grid, removing the WrapPanel and replacing it with a grid.

Other similar questions suggested removing StackPanel (which I did but made no difference) or using ScrollViewer (which did not work).

The Page that hosts the UserControl uses a GestureListener - I removed that and it still made no difference.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="SteelBlue">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Search"
               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />-->

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Search Type"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <RadioButton Content="RMB/RSD"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchType, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RMB, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <RadioButton Content="Name"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchType, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Search Term"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding SearchTerm, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 InputScope="{Binding SearchTermInputScope}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:SelectAllOnFocusBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>

    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Content="Find"
            cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding FindDeliveryPointsCommand}" />

    <ListBox Grid.Row="3"
             ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   Width="480"
                                   Background="{Binding RMB, Converter={StaticResource alternateColorConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RMB}"
                               FontSize="26"
                               Foreground="Navy"
                               Padding="5"
                               Width="60" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HouseholdName}"
                               FontSize="26"
                               Foreground="Navy"
                               Padding="5"
                               Width="420" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StreetWithRRN}"
                               FontSize="26"
                               Foreground="Navy"
                               Padding="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street.Locality.Name}"
                               FontSize="26"
                               Foreground="Navy"
                               Padding="5" />
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit too complex. I would recommend creating a new page with a LIstBox full of strings, verify that this scrolls properly. Then slowly add back the code you have above. When it stops working, you have found your cause! Note ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility is not needed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Specify ListBox.Height - something like Height="200". As it is now, ListBox expands automatically to accomodate all loaded items and it grows out of the screen. As a result you get large page with no scroller.

When you add ListBox.Height, the ListBox area won't grow. Instead ListBox ScrollViewer will be activated and you'll get the effect you need.

Comment: thankyou - your solution worked perfectly.  Fairly obvious I guess - but I had missed it.

Comment: But what to do, if list changes dynamically, and it is not possible to set height?

Comment: Here i opt to put height="550", this show in all screen of windows phone emulator.

Comment: Old thread, but was stuck on this just now. I found this solution works, even for nested bound lists, except for some reason if the Height goes over the screen height. It doesn't matter if your listbox ends up being longer than the screen - setting the Height to eg Height="550" will work.

Answer (score 1):

I use databinding when the ListBox's Height changed depending on the other controls on the page.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">            
        <ListBox x:Name="LstSample" Height="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="None"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="45"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group}" FontSize="25"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```